# Langchain - Word Documents

Tags: openai-api, langchain

I am trying to query a stack of word documents using langchain, yet I get the following traceback.

May I ask what's the argument that's expected here?

Also, side question, is there a way to do such a query locally (without internet access and openai)?

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File c:\data\langchain\langchaintest.py:44
    index = VectorstoreIndexCreator().from_loaders(loaders)

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\langchain\indexes\vectorstore.py:72 in from_loaders
    docs.extend(loader.load())

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\langchain\document_loaders\text.py:17 in load
    with open(self.file_path, encoding=self.encoding) as f:

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:
```

... where "invalid argument: " is followed by the raw text from the word document.

Code:

```
import os
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "xxxxxx"


import os
import docx
from langchain.document_loaders import TextLoader

# Function to get text from a docx file
def get_text_from_docx(file_path):
    doc = docx.Document(file_path)
    full_text = []
    for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
        full_text.append(paragraph.text)
    
    return '\n'.join(full_text)

# Load multiple Word documents
folder_path = 'C:/Data/langchain'
word_files = [os.path.join(folder_path, file) for file in os.listdir(folder_path) if file.endswith('.docx')]

loaders = []
for word_file in word_files:
    text = get_text_from_docx(word_file)
    loader = TextLoader(text)
    loaders.append(loader)
    
    
from langchain.indexes import VectorstoreIndexCreator

index = VectorstoreIndexCreator().from_loaders(loaders)

query = "What are the main points discussed in the documents?"

responses = index.query(query)
print(responses)

results_with_source=index.query_with_sources(query)
print(results_with_source)
```

Comment: [PrivateDocBot](https://github.com/Abhi5h3k/PrivateDocBot)

Created using langchain and chainlit 

It also streams using langchain just like ChatGpt it displays word by word and works locally on PDF data. ‍ 

code reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `TextLoader` expects a file path string, not raw text - it is designed to load in text files.  Here's the [`TextLoader.__init__()` definition](https://github.com/hwchase17/langchain/blob/04b74d0446bdb8fc1f9e544d2f164a59bbd0df0c/langchain/document_loaders/text.py#LL7C1-L9C1):

```
class TextLoader(BaseLoader):
    """Load text files."""

    def __init__(self, file_path: str, encoding: Optional[str] = None):
        """Initialize with file path."""
        self.file_path = file_path
        self.encoding = encoding
```

You might find the [`Docx2txtLoader`](https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/modules/indexes/document_loaders/examples/microsoft_word.html) useful for working with Word docs.